# Is the phrase 他【ほか】を利【り】する ambiguous?

Tags: words, ambiguity, collocations

Is the phrase 他【ほか】を利【り】する ambiguous?

I found it here:

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/他/#je-44494](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E4%BB%96/#je-44494)

他【ほか】を利【り】する
benefit others

Could this example also mean *exploit others*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary definitions of 利する seem indeed confusing:

> ##### [利する](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%88%A9%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)
>
> １ 利益がある。また、利益を得る。「―・するところの大きい事業」
> ２ 利益を与える。「双方を―・する取引」
> ３ うまく用いる。巧みに使う。利用する。「地形を―・して公園をつくる」「職権を―・する」

But the most common usage is 2, or "to benefit someone/something". The third definition is the least common. When the object of 利する is a human or an organization, I think it always means "to benefit". This includes cases where the object is 他 ("others; other people").